# how to use utf-8 in mPDF library - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8

I want to use `[mpdf][1]` library in `codeigniter` framework .

now,I want to use `utf-8` for persian language .

```
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
    $html = iconv("utf-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
    $pdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
    $pdf->mirrorMargins = true;
    $pdf->SetFooter($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'|{PAGENO}|'.date(DATE_RFC822)); // Add a footer for good measure <img src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/72x72/1f609.png" alt="" draggable="false" class="emoji">
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $html); // write the HTML into the PDF
    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, 'F'); // save to file because we can
```

the result of `pdf` file :

[image]

//libraries/pdf.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class pdf {

    function pdf()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
    }

    function load($param=NULL)
    {
        include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        if ($params == NULL)
        {
            $param = '"fa","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';       
        }

        return new mPDF($param);
    }
}
```